Scopus Search API - Error 400 using cursor
I'm extracting details from research articles using the Scopus Search API and the cursor function for pagination. At one of the iterations, I get a 400 error. See below:
Progress: 36725 items retrieved
Iteration: 1470, Cursor: AoJR/oJNMjItczIuMC04NTA3MjE4NzA5Ng==

Progress: 36750 items retrieved
Iteration: 1471, Cursor: AoJR/oJNMjItczIuMC04NTA3MTA5NjA0Mg==

Progress: 36775 items retrieved
Iteration: 1472, Cursor: AoJR/oJNMjItczIuMC04NTA2OTk4ODc2Mw==

Progress: 36800 items retrieved
Iteration: 1473, Cursor: AoJR/oJNMjItczIuMC04NTA2NjMwMDY0Mg==

Progress: 36825 items retrieved
Iteration: 1474, Cursor: AoJR/oJNMjItczIuMC04NTA1ODM4MjQwMQ==

Progress: 36850 items retrieved
Iteration: 1475, Cursor: AoJX+YJNMjItczIuMC04NTA3Nzc5MDY5MQ==

Progress: 36875 items retrieved
**Error: 400, {"service-error":{"status":{"statusCode":"INVALID_INPUT","statusText":"Invalid Input (cursor)"}}}

I think this is because the cursor value contains a "+" instead of a "/", as all the previous cursors seem to work fine. However, I'm not sure about this and I don't know how to solve this issue.
This is my code so far:
def elsevier_scroll(search_url, query):
    all_results = []
    cursor = "*" # Start with "*" to indicate the beginning
    iteration_count = 0
    
    while cursor:
        iteration_count += 1
        response = elsevier_api(search_url, query, cursor)
        
        if response is None:
            break

        entries = response.get('search-results', {}).get('entry', [])

        if not entries:
            break  # Exit the loop if there are no more results

        cursor = response.get('search-results', {}).get('cursor', {}).get('@next') # Get next cursor to move to next page
        # decoded_cursor = urllib.parse.unquote(cursor)


        print(f"Iteration: {iteration_count}, Cursor: {cursor}")  # Print cursor value

        for entry in entries:
            extracted_info = extract_info(entry)
            all_results.append(extracted_info)

        print(f"Progress: {len(all_results)} items retrieved")
    
    return all_results


I would appreciate any advice on the matter.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
